# How to insert and show html code in jQuery Terminal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, terminal, jquery-terminal

I want to use [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/9dk1zpss/) but changing the `textArea` to a `div`or any other [jQuery terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) situable object to show it in `term.echo()`.

I'm doing that by changing html line 1 for `<div id="txtA"></div>`

and line 7 of javascript for `document.getElementById('txtA').innerHTML = diff;`

**Can I show html in the jQuery Console?**

Something like `term.echo('<span id=\"txtA\"></span>')` ??
I'm getting the code like if I were using `<pre></pre>`

Thanks.

Comment: What the heck is the "jQuery Terminal/Console"?

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: You want `term.echo('<span id=\"txtA\"></span>', {raw: true})` but you need to call getElementById inside setTimeout otherwise it will not work when you resize the browser, the node will be removed and replaced by new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, raw will output raw html into terminal and finalize will be called when node is added so you can modify it, finalize will also be called when terminal is resized.

```
term.echo('<span id=\"txtA\"></span>', {
  raw: true,
  finalize: function(div) {
    document.getElementById('txtA').innerHTML = diff;
    // or using jQuery
    div.find('#txtA').html(diff);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** from version [2.9.0](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#290)

You can echo DOM nodes and jQuery objects.

```js
term.echo($('<span id="txtA"></span>'));
```

Note that if you don't want to lose your content on resize you still need to use finalize options.